# 01722-invalid-number error

Tags: sql, oracle, cognos-8

```
SELECT  * FROM COACH_SHOP_OPERATION_F
WHERE TRUNC(coach_last_event_dt)=TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('MAY 25,2015','DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
```

Running this query results in error:

> 01722-invalid-number

Comment: try removing the comma in the date string

Comment: `TO_CHAR('MAY 25,2015','DD-MON-YYYY')` does not make ***any*** sense. Please read the manual on what `to_char()` does.

Comment: Yeah it should be to_date, first cast the string to a date in the current format and then cast to different format is how I got it to work

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
SELECT  * FROM COACH_SHOP_OPERATION_F
WHERE TRUNC(coach_last_event_dt)=TO_DATE('MAY 25,2015','MON DD,YY')
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1900) (with thanks to Alex Poole)

Comment: Why nested `to_date` calls - you're relying on NLS settings, for no benefit. And why not match the actual date model, [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7db59d16c/1900)? (Though this still assumes NLS date language is English, for the month abbreviation)

Comment: yeah I seem to have pasted a different query than what I actually used, don't know how that happened, I was using MON DD,YY

Comment: and didn't know you couldn't cast date to a different format in oracle, same result after second cast so I guess all dates are shown in in format MON, DD YY , unless that's just a sqlfiddle thing, I've never used an oracle system as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Your date is language related, therefore you should add additional parameter as (example for german language):

```
TO_DATE('MAI 25,2015','MONTH DD,YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = GERMAN')
```

or for english language

```
TO_DATE('MAY 25,2015','MONTH DD,YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH')
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 

> TO_CHAR('MAY 25,2015','DD-MON-YYYY')
>   
>   `'MAY 25,2015'` is a **string**, and you are using **TO_CHAR** on a string, makes no sense. You need **TO_DATE** to convert a string into DATE, and TO_CHAR to convert DATE into string to display in your desired format.

2. 

> 'MAY 25,2015','DD-MON-YYYY'
>   
>   The **format model** is not matching. It should be:

```
MON DD,YYYY
```

3. 

> TO_DATE(TO_CHAR('MAY 25,2015','DD-MON-YYYY'),'DD-MON-YYYY')
>   
>   You are depending on the **locale-specific NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE**. It might not be the same for other users.

```
TO_DATE('MAY 25,2015','MON DD,YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH')
```

4. 

> TRUNC(coach_last_event_dt)
>   
>   Applying **TRUNC** would suppress any regular **index** usage. It is better to use a **Date Range condition**. For example,

```
 between to_date('25/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY')
    and to_date('25/05/2015','DD/MM/YYYY') + 1;
```

Your modified query would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM COACH_SHOP_OPERATION_F
WHERE coach_last_event_dt 
BETWEEN 
   TO_DATE('MAY 25,2015','MON DD,YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH') 
AND 
   TO_DATE('MAY 25,2015','MON DD,YYYY', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ENGLISH') + 1;
```